# Array As Grid, How to Move Diagonally?

Tags: java, arrays, math

I have an array of size n^2 representing a square grid of size nxn.

I want to get from any square (0 to (n^2)-1) to the top-right most square you can get to moving diagonally in a straight line.

I already figured out that to get to the top-left most square is to take the current square x and the top-left most square is x%(n+1).

Does anyone know a similar method for top-right most square? Thanks!

Comment: By diagonally do you mean at 45 degree angles only? Or do you mean by moving along the axes. Your equation isn't giving me very consistent results.

Comment: Do you have to number the squares this way? IMO it would be easier if you used a two-dimensional array and a coordinate system, eg: `(0,0)` is the top-left square, `(n-1, n-1)` is the bottom-right

Comment: You are not providing enough information to answer this question.  Is the array ordered like array[0] = 0,0, array[1]=0,1 or array[1]=1,0?  Is the coordinate system 0,0 is lower left or upper left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood at all what you're trying to achieve, all you need to do is connect the two points with a straight line and using the line formulas calculate the coordinates of the cells that it goes through. You may use for this the [Bresenham's line drawing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).